# Not able to write image from local folder to folder in tomcat servrer

Tags: jakarta-ee

enter link description hereHi i am using the below code to store image from local folder to folder in tomcat.
some image is created in tht folder but size is 0.i m unable to find the solution.please help
same is working when when runni same code from eclipse luna in tomcat server.
running from outside,image size is 0.

```
File file = new File(filepath);
        BufferedImage image=null; 
        OutputStream stream=null;

        try
        {
            stream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    context.getRealPath("/TempJobDescriptionImages/"+file.getName())));
        /*          "http://localhost:8080/Profiles/WebContent/TempJobDescriptionImages/"+file.getName())); // Your output
*/      

            System.out.println(context.getRealPath("/TempJobDescriptionImages/"+file.getName()));
        BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(file);
        int width          = bimg.getWidth();
        int height         = bimg.getHeight();
        byte[] bytes = extractBytes(filepath); // Your image bytes
        image= createRGBImage(bytes, width, height);

        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", stream);
        stream.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(""+e);
        }

    private static BufferedImage createRGBImage(byte[] bytes, int width, int height) {
        DataBufferByte buffer = new DataBufferByte(bytes, bytes.length);
        ColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), new int[]{8, 8, 8}, false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
        return new BufferedImage(cm, Raster.createInterleavedRaster(buffer, width, height, width * 3, 3, new int[]{0, 1, 2}, null), false, null);
    }

    public byte[] extractBytes (String ImageName) throws IOException {
         // open image
         File imgPath = new File(ImageName);
         BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);

         // get DataBufferBytes from Raster
         WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage .getRaster();
         DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

         return ( data.getData() );
        }
```

Comment: If this is just a file copy why not just call [java.nio.file.Files.copy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...))?

Comment: no this is not jus file copy...this is image file.

Comment: also in tht destination folder some default image is created with size 0....so destination path given is correct but writing the image from local folder to folder in tomcat is problem..please help anybody.thanks

Comment: If you are deliberately doing some image processing then write a unit test and debug it. But you do not need to go to all that trouble if you're just copying it, image file or not.

Comment: ok as u suggested I am doin simple...removed processing n just writing...but still same problem